# Trouble downloading files in Dropbox Python API v2

Tags: python, ffmpeg, dropbox-api, .mov

I'm trying to download .mov files from Dropbox, manipulate them with ffmpeg, and upload back to Dropbox, but I'm getting an error when I use the files_download method.

I'm able to read files from Dropbox without any problem using dbx.files_list_folder

When trying to download files, I've used the following:

```py
import dropbox
access_token = 'MY TOKEN'
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token)
metadata,file=dbx.files_download('path to .mov file')
```

and I get the error

```py
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='content.dropboxapi.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /2/files/download (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

I don't know if this is a cause, but I didn't use the Dropbox app key or app secret in setting things up. In going through the API v2 setup, it looked like all you need is the API Access token, but I'm wondering if there's a permissions error.

I'll only be using this app for myself--it's not meant for production.

Comment: It looks like there was an issue establishing a connection to the Dropbox API content servers, when validating the certificate in particular. They're currently being served with valid certificates and working for me though. Is there anything on your network connection, e.g., firewall, proxy, anti-virus, etc. that may be interfering with your connection to content.dropboxapi.com?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything network-related. One possibility is that I'm not the admin on the account, just a member. Would that stop me from downloading/uploading via the API? I'm able to download/upload through Dropbox, so figured I'd be able to do so through API as well.

Comment: That wouldn't prevent you from uploading or downloading via the API. Any sort of issue like that would result in an error from the Dropbox API service itself anyway, not at the network layer like you're seeing. Are you still seeing this issue? If so, can you try it on another computer/server and network connection to see if it's specific to one?

Comment: @Greg, got it working, thanks for the help. My IT team had to whitelist content.dropboxapi.com since apparently the SDK doesn't use the built-in Windows certificate store, which causes the SSL handshake to fail